# Can't access innerText property using Puppeteer - .$$eval and .$$ is not yielding results - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web-crawler, puppeteer

I am working on a web **scraper** that searches Google for certain things and then pulls text from the result page, and I am having an issue getting Puppeteer to return the text I need. What I want to return is an array of strings.

Let's say I have a couple nested divs within a div, and each has text like so:

```
 <div class='mainDiv'>
   <div>Mary Doe </div>
   <div> James Dean </div>
 </div>
```

In the DOM, I can do the following to get the result I need:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.mainDiv')[0].innerText.split('\n')
```

This yields: `["Mary Doe", "James Dean"]`.

I understand that Puppeteer doesn't return NodeLists, and instead it uses JSHandles, but I still can't figure out how to get any information using the prescribed methods. See below for what I have tried in Puppeteer and the corresponding console output:

In every scenario, I do `await page.waitFor('selector')` to start.

Scenario 1 (using `.$$eval()`):

```
const genreElements = await page.$$eval('div.mainDiv', el => el);
console.log(genreElements) // []
```

Scenario 2 (using `evaluate`):

```
function extractItems() {
   const extractedElements = document.querySelectorAll('div.mainDiv')[0].innerText.split('\n')
   return extractedElements
}
      
let items = await page.evaluate(extractItems)
console.log(items) // UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined
```

Scenario 3 (using `evaluateHandle`):

```
const selectorHandle = await page.evaluateHandle(() => document.querySelectorAll('div.mainDiv'))
const resultHandle = await page.evaluate(x => x[0], selectorHandle)
console.log(resultHandle) // undefined
```

Any help or guidance on how I am implementing or how to achieve what I am looking to do is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of `querySelectorAll()[0]` (get all, then throw everything away but the first) why not `querySelector()` (get the first)?

Answer (score 4):

#### Use page.$$eval() or page.evaluate():

You can use [`page.$$eval()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args) or [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) to run [`Array.from(`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)[`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)[`)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) within the page context and [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) of each element to the result array:

```
const names_1 = await page.$$eval('.mainDiv > div', divs => divs.map(div => div.innerText));
const names_2 = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.mainDiv > div'), div => div.innerText));
```

> **Note:** Keep in mind that if you use Puppeteer to automate searches on Google, you may be temporarily blocked and end up with an ["Unusual traffic from your computer network"](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640) notice, requiring you to solve a [reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha). This may break your web scraper, so proceed with caution.

Comment: thank you. Any suggestions on how to avoid being blocked? I am only searching for an artist genre and only on the first page

Comment: @NigelFinley I would take a look at [Search engine scraping - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_scraping) - specifically the [Methods of scraping Google, Bing or Yahoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_scraping#Methods_of_scraping_Google,_Bing_or_Yahoo) section.

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
let names = page.evaluate(() => [...document.querySelectorAll('.mainDiv div')].map(div => div.innerText))
```

That way you can test the whole thing in the chrome console.

Answer (score 1):

Using **[page.$eval](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args)**:

```
const names = await page.$eval('.mainDiv', (element) => {
    return element.innerText
});
```

Here the element is retrieved by selector and directly passed to the function to be evaluated.

Using **[page.evaluate](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args)**:

```
const namesElem = await page.$('.mainDiv');
const names = await page.evaluate(namesElem => namesElem.innerText, namesElem);
```

This is basically the first method split up into two steps. The interesting part is that [ElementHandles](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle) can be passed as arguments in page.evaluate() and can be evaluated like [JSHandles](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-jshandle).

Note that for simplicity and clarification I used the methods for retrieving single elements. But page.$$() and page.$$eval() work the same way while selecting multiple elements and returning an array instead.

Comment: I like how clean & simple the first method is. 